# Create a stream builder for JSON data Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-streambuilder

I'm getting JSON data from API using stream and the `snapshot.data` shows null.

It works fine on FutureBuilder but I need Streambuilder for continues data.

Here is the full code:

**Stream: (my current stream to call the API )**

```
final Stream<Notifications> _fetchDataStream = (() {
  late final StreamController<Notifications> controller;
  controller = StreamController<Notifications>(
    onListen: () async {
      final request = http.StreamedRequest(
          'GET',
          Uri.https('ntfy.sh', '/mytopic/json',
              {'poll': '1'}));

      request.sink.close();
      var result = await request.send();
      var response = await http.Response.fromStream(result);
      Notifications nots = Notifications();
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.body);
        Notifications.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
      } else {
        // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
        // then throw an exception.
        throw Exception('Failed to load album');
      }
      controller.add(Notifications());
      await controller.close();
    },
  );
  return controller.stream;
})();
```

**StreamBuilder: (my current streambuilder)**

```
StreamBuilder<Notifications>(
            stream: _fetchDataStream,
            builder:
                (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Notifications> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text('${snapshot.data}');
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
```

**modal.dart (to store the json values)**

```
class Notifications {
  String? id;
  int? time;
  int? expires;
  String? event;
  String? topic;
  String? title;
  String? message;

  Notifications(
      {this.id,
      this.time,
      this.expires,
      this.event,
      this.topic,
      this.title,
      this.message});

  Notifications.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    time = json['time'];
    expires = json['expires'];
    event = json['event'];
    topic = json['topic'];
    title = json['title'];
    message = json['message'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['time'] = this.time;
    data['expires'] = this.expires;
    data['event'] = this.event;
    data['topic'] = this.topic;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    return data;
  }
}
```

**Expected JSON DATA (getting from the api)**

```
{"id":"coOhkyN1YxBD","time":1692893929,"expires":1698077929,"event":"message","topic":"mytopic","message":"This is a test notification from the ntfy Android app. It has a level 5 priority. If you send another, it may look different.","priority":5,"tags":["this-is-a-tag","rsync"]}
{"id":"0snbxhbGEehW","time":1697330037,"expires":1697373237,"event":"message","topic":"mytopic","message":"Backup successful "}
{"id":"PvcsTrRxqb0m","time":1697352352,"expires":1697395552,"event":"message","topic":"mytopic","message":"Backup successful "}
{"id":"ZDGew6HgIbue","time":1697352368,"expires":1697395568,"event":"message","topic":"mytopic","message":"Bing Chilling"}
{"id":"I20EDvVvwgMr","time":1697352425,"expires":1697395625,"event":"message","topic":"mytopic","message":"lsd done running"}
{"id":"GX02kf13Y0Xd","time":1697352645,"expires":1697395845,"event":"message","topic":"mytopic","message":"Hello Motu"}
{"id":"nN6Jnsrf5jyI","time":1697355413,"expires":1697398613,"event":"message","topic":"mytopic","message":"Backup successful "}
{"id":"83L6jGQlSfYk","time":1697360074,"expires":1697403274,"event":"message","topic":"mytopic","message":"Backup successful "}
{"id":"Dnj8RmVCFEwr","time":1697361179,"expires":1697404379,"event":"message","topic":"mytopic","message":"Would You Kill the Fat Man? [pdf] (utilitarianism.com) book"}
{"id":"QIzLhHdI5mww","time":1697362404,"expires":1697405604,"event":"message","topic":"mytopic","message":"card+scanned"}
```

I need to get the data in Streambuilder

Comment: "but I need Streambuilder for continues data." what do you mean by that? du you want to poll your API periodically (for example every, say, 60 seconds)? if so just use `Stream.periodic` construstor

Comment: no if you fetch data through StreamBuilder it will update the UI without need of reload of the widget. if a new data added to the json the UI will automatically shows the new data I don't want to refresh to the get the data. that's what I meant by that.

Comment: can you check my code to find the error in the Stream? I couldn't get the data now. the data is not a JSON data its streamed json

Comment: ok, how many times do you want to call `http.StreamedRequest` method? it you want to call it once you cannot get any changes - you will get only one snapshot of data and you don't need `StreamBuildrr` for that: `FutureBuilder` is good enough

Comment: no i want to listen to the stream all the time that's why I need StreamBuilder. I know that FutureBuilder can get the data once I don't need that

Comment: so you have to call your API multiple times, there is no other way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255632/discussion-between-iamrishan-and-pskink).